# why doesn't .d.ts file work in vscode app?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, .d.ts

I write a new .d.ts file in my vscode project, and when I continue to code, I can't get intelligence tips.However, I reopen the vscode, I can get those tips.So, Why? How to make .d.ts file work in vscode without reopening?

Comment: what if you run command `Reload Window`

Comment: Yes, Reload Window could help me solve this problem, but I don't wanna run this command every time

Comment: how often do you change the `.d.ts` file? It looks like they are read on workspace open by the Language Service Provider if you have a js or ts file open and there is no file watch on them like with settings

Comment: I don't often change the file actually, but I'm really curious about why it can't work immediately.Maybe some vscode plugins help me watch the changes in  **.d.ts** file？

Comment: if the LSP does not load the new file you don't get the new intellisence